# Discrete IC Printed label

Tags: transistors, diodes

How can I identify a transistor PMOS, when I only know the printed label/legend in it "T9F"?
and the same to identify a zener or diode, when I only know the printed label/legend in it "2U90"?

Comment: In a schematic? In what software? Or do you mean identify them through electrical characteristics?
Otherwise you could use nail polish to mark them?

Comment: The package is also an important clue in determining a unique ID.

Answer (score 1):

Your T9F is a PLVA665A Zener Diode.  Specs for it can easily be found through google.  
[Such as here.](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PLVA6XXA_SERIES.pdf)   That is a 6.5V Zener, rated for 250mA.

Code T9F found in [this book - SMD-PHILIPS Marking Codes Small Signal Transistors and Diodes.](http://matthieu.benoit.free.fr/cross/competitive/philips/SMD-PHILIPS.pdf)  Other copies of the book can be found as PDF through google.

I can't find anything at all about the 2U90.  Could you post a picture of it?